# Chaos Frame penalty for taking no action in training

Tags: tactics-ogre-psp, tactics-ogre

In Tactics Ogre (the SNES/PSX version specifically, but the answer may be the same for the PSP version) how much a character likes you and the chaos frame for their nationality can drop if you make them take neither an action nor a movement order during their turn.

However, during training I frequently want my higher level characters to sit in place so my lower level characters can shoot them in the back repeatedly. At the same time, lowering their affinity with you and their nationality's chaos frame is very bad so I issue an order to move to their current position, facing the same direction.

My question(s) is thus:

- Can the chaos frame and/or affinity toward Denim be harmed in training by forcing your troops to end their turn with no movement and no action?
- If the previous answer is yes, will making a troop take a move order without actually moving or changing orientation prevent that drop in training?
- If the first answer is no, will making a troop take a move order without actually moving or changing orientation prevent that drop in actual combat?

(Note that moving without actually *moving* counts as a move as far as the wait mechanics are concerned. I believe you retain 20% of your turn order if you only move or only take an action, including my [no-op](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) move.  You retain 40% if you truly wait with no move at all and no action. In training the real advantage is just saving myself some time by not having to select the no-op move all the time.)

Edit: Source for loyalty dropping from not acting: http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/198881-tactics-ogre/faqs/32399

Comment: Training only exists in the SNES/PSX version.  There is no such thing in the PSP remake, due to the way they modified the classes.

Comment: Also, I'm curious where you got the info about their affection dropping if you just gave them a wait order.  Do you have a source?

Comment: @Frank I'll look it up when I get a chance. Pretty sure it was GameFAQs somewhere. Something about a percentage chance of it dropping...